# Angularjs+spring boot (need of two different controllers)

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

Why we create two controllers while implementing spring boot with angular js.

One for communicating with web and another for rest services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you actually don't need two controllers ( if you are talking about for one endpoint, two controllers in server side ). check out my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861231/spring-boot-ngroute/46861891#46861891) question here. It may explain.

Update:

The Route

```
'use strict'

angular.module('TestApp' , ["ngRoute"])
       .config(function($routeProvider){

            $routeProvider
            .when('/' , {
                templateUrl : "view/main.html",
                controller : 'MainController',
                controllerAs : 'main'
            })
            .when('/test' , {
                templateUrl : "view/test.html",
                controller : 'TestController',
                controllerAs : 'test'
            })
            .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
            });
       });
```

and The controller

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class ServerController {


}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18794289)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, did not know that. updated

Comment: That is much better, Thanks @TheTechGuy