# Spring Boot ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, ngroute

I'm trying to make a single page application with a Spring back end and an AngularJS front end. I've followed tutorials and looked up similar questions but ngRoute just doesn't seem to work with a Spring back end (I got it to work with a NodeJS back end).

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Spring Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="index" ng-controller="indexController">
    <a href="/test">test</a>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>

</html>
```

test.html

```
<div>
    Template loaded
</div>
```

index.js

```
'use strict';

const indexModule = angular.module('index', ['ngRoute']);

indexModule.controller("indexController", function indexController($scope) {

});

indexModule.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/test', {templateUrl: 'test.html'});
});
```

SringDemoController.java

```
package com.springdemo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class SpringDemoController {

    @RequestMapping({ "/" })
    public String getIndexTemplate() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiCRs.png) when I click the link and the URL changes to http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: Project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjrxN.png

Comment: You haven't configured the locationProvider to use the HML5 mode. So your link isn't pointing to your angular test route. It tries to load the /test path from the server. ANd you have nothing configured for this path on the server, hence the 404 error. If your intention is to avoid the HTML5 mode, the link should be `<a href="#!/test">test</a>`. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: I've added "$routeProvider.html5Mode(true);". But if I add @RequestMapping("/test") and return the test template in my Java controller, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using ng-view? It would make it a multiple page app.

Comment: Where did I say the the server should return the test template for /test? It shouldn't. With html5 mode turned on, your link should work fine. What won't work though is if you refresh the page when you're on your /test view, because that will once again make a request to /test. The server should serve the index.html page for /test and all the other URLs of your app.

Comment: I though that's what you meant by having nothing configured for the path on the server. I am still getting the template not found error after setting the route provider to html5 mode (I haven't made any other changes). Here's my console log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCkZS.png. The last 3 lines are displayed when I click my link

Comment: You're saying that you "still" have the template not found. But that's not what the error you post is about. The error you posted is about /test not being found. Not the template. All you should have on the server to make things work (except for the /test page refresh) is static files: index.html, test.html, and index.js. Make sure these three static files are served correctly, then go to index.html, open your network dev tools panel, click on the link, and see what happens.

Comment: I mean I am still getting the error of my post's original linked screenshot

Comment: I am wondering since you have angularjs why you want the server to return the template?

Comment: Note that you said you used $routeProvider.html5Mode(true), but there is no such method in $routeProvider. It's on $locationProvider. Open your console. look at errors and fix them.

Comment: @myCode I don't want Spring to do that and I don't know why it keeps asking for a template from the server  :(

Comment: give me a min ;)

Comment: @JBNizet No errors on the IntelliJ console and the error on Chrome's dev tool is not really helpful: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulyWY.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKtlu.png

Comment: Look at errors in the **console** tab of Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Then what you said you did in the comments is not correct. Post your updated code. All of it. In your question. And post the structure of your spring boot project. Note that you're loading ../static/index.js which is most probably not the right URL for your script either, since you're already at the root, and `..` doesn't make sense. Check at least that your JS code is running. Use your debugger. Add console.log() in the code.

Comment: @JBNizet Got it to work, thank you so much! The errors started appearing when I changed the call to $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); Then I moved the test.html file in the same folder as index.js and added a base href and it worked. Now I just need to fix the routing on reload. 
Thank you for being patient with me!

Comment: @Philippe check out the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

The Index page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test title</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="TestApp">

    <div>
        <h1>The Index</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a ng-href="#!/test"> Temp One</a>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular-route.js"></script>


 <script src="js/config.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controller/main.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controller/test.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

The Router config (its called config.js)

```
'use strict'

angular.module('TestApp' , ["ngRoute"])
       .config(function($routeProvider){

            $routeProvider
            .when('/' , {
                templateUrl : "view/main.html",
                controller : 'MainController',
                controllerAs : 'main'
            })
            .when('/test' , {
                templateUrl : "view/test.html",
                controller : 'TestController',
                controllerAs : 'test'
            })
            .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
            });
       });
```

And the `server-side controller` for the route :

```
package com.testApp;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ServerController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String getTestTemp() {
        return "static/test";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :** 
 actually, the method inside the ServerController is not needed. It can be written as follows

```
package com.testApp;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class ServerController {


}
```

So if you write any REST method in this controller, the endpoint from both client and server side will be `/test/{the Name of your endPoint }`

Here is the Project Structure 
[image: The structure]

If you add more templates, make sure you create the `route`on the client side and also the server side

Comment: Does the page still display properly if you reload on the test page?

Comment: yeah  it does :D

Comment: you dont have to do anything else to make this issue work

Comment: Just tested your code, works like a charm. Thank you so much!